# I am one of four

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am one of four,
>
> my anagram could be the floor.
>
> My abbreviation is number five,
>
> overall, I am where you can drive.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you be

> East

I am one of four,

> One of four directions

my anagram could be the floor.

> Seat

My abbreviation is number five,

> E, E is the 5th letter

overall, I am where you can drive

> You can drive Eastward. Like in the direction of East...

Comment: last line probably means driving in that direction

Comment: Oh I'll include that! Thanks. Probably the most obvious application of the word, dunno how I missed that :P

Answer (score 2):

## Partial Answer:

> **CARPET**.

`I am one of four,`

> The **four** main types of flooring are:

- > Timber (that includes hardwood, laminate, bamboo and vinyl);

- > Stone (particularly polished, i.e. granite, marble, tile);

- > Cork; and

- > **Carpet**.

> There are also the four most common **pets** (from car**pet**): dogs, cats, fish and birds; though for some reason, rabbits are currently becoming popular :P

`My anagram could be the floor.`

> Ehhh, not really its anagram, but more of its **definition**...

`My abbreviation is number five,`

> The abbreviation of **CARPET** can be **CP** which also stands for **Chest Pain**. There are [**five** main deadly causes of chest pain](https://www.jems.com/articles/print/volume-42/issue-1/features/the-five-deadly-causes-of-chest-pain-other-than-myocardial-infarction.html)${}^1$ apart from myocardial infarction (i.e. a heart attack), as that is more of heart pain which only causes chest pain because of where the heart is (significantly different). 
>  <sub>${}^1$The link might prove to be disturbing, so beware.</sub>

`Overall, I am where you can drive.`

> **CAR**PET.

`What am I?`

> **CARPET**?

Comment: Yes, I expected a downvote for this one. This is a close answer, but perhaps I should have saved this for a comment. @downvoter, do you recommend I delete it?